# SSIS Excel column name reading from file

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a source file, has columns names with length as more than 100.

Column name are same upto 80 characters and remaining 20 characters will be different, please find below example.

```
ABC_XXXX_MNOAP : XYZABC_PAGELOADER_CLICKS_MANOPD_YXBDBAGD : VIEWS
ABC_XXXX_MNOAP : XYZABC_PAGELOADER_CLICKS_MANOPD_YXBDBAGD : CLICKS & THROGHS
```

While i am loading this file in to ssis, full column name is not loading and it is trimming.

Error thrown was

> There is more than one data source column with same

Please help me how to get full metadata from excel

Comment: You could get around this by configuring your Excel source using `IMEX=1`. You would then need to map F1,F2,F3 etc.There are a number articles about this. For example [link]https://www.concentra.co.uk/blog/why-ssis-always-gets-excel-data-types-wrong-and-how-to-fix-it

Comment: After following process mentioned in provided link. Unable to read file, please help me how can i resolve this?

Comment: Could be a problem with your connection string(i.e. the one ending with `IMEX=1`). Could you post this?